# PHP / MYSQL UPDATE Show 0 in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to UPDATE specific row in database.

the Update Process work But one of the field does not update {Well it does update but when i check the database it show 0 and i can not find out what is the problem with the code}

any help would be great.

the problem its member_id.

member_id its int data type in database.

the Update Code

```
  if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
$plan_id=$_POST['plan_id'];
$member_id=$_POST['member_id'];
$trainer_id=$_POST['trainer_id'];
$exercise_id=$_POST['exercise_id'];
$Set=$_POST['Set'];
$weight=$_POST['weight'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$memberadd="No";
$query = "UPDATE gym_plan SET ";
$query.= "exercise_id = {$exercise_id}, ";
$query.= "exercise_set = '{$Set}', ";
$query.= "trainer_id = {$trainer_id}, ";
$query.= "member_id = {$member_id}, ";
$query.= "comment = '{$comment}', ";
$query.= "member_id = '{$memberadd}', ";
$query.= "weight = '{$weight}' ";
$query.= "WHERE plan_id = {$plan_id}; ";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
echo 'my SQL query is: '.$query;
echo "<br/>";
if ($result) 
    {
        //header("Location:editex.php");
$message2="The Exercise Has Been Updated";
$_SESSION['edit-ex']=$message2;
    }// to check if the query run then show this message
else
    {
    die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

and the Full Code is

```
<?php 
session_start();
$message2="";
require_once("db_connection.php"); 
$id = $_SESSION['staff_id'];
if (isset($_SESSION  ['username']))
{
    if($_SESSION['access_level']==3)
    {
    $message= "welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']." !<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location:index.php");
        $goaway="You Don't Have Privilege To Check This Page";
        $_SESSION['noway']=$goaway;
    }

}
else 
{
header("Location:index.php");
}
if( isset($_GET['edit']))
{
        $id2 = $_GET['edit'];
        $member_id=$_SESSION['member_id'];
        $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gym_plan WHERE member_id='$member_id' AND exercise_id='$id2'");
}
if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
$plan_id=$_POST['plan_id'];
$member_id=$_POST['member_id'];
$trainer_id=$_POST['trainer_id'];
$exercise_id=$_POST['exercise_id'];
$Set=$_POST['Set'];
$weight=$_POST['weight'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$memberadd="No";
$query = "UPDATE gym_plan SET ";
$query.= "exercise_id = {$exercise_id}, ";
$query.= "exercise_set = '{$Set}', ";
$query.= "trainer_id = {$trainer_id}, ";
$query.= "member_id = {$member_id}, ";
$query.= "comment = '{$comment}', ";
$query.= "member_id = '{$memberadd}', ";
$query.= "weight = '{$weight}' ";
$query.= "WHERE plan_id = {$plan_id}; ";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
echo 'my SQL query is: '.$query;
echo "<br/>";
if ($result) 
    {
        //header("Location:editex.php");
$message2="The Exercise Has Been Updated";
$_SESSION['edit-ex']=$message2;
    }// to check if the query run then show this message
else
    {
    die(mysql_error());
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$br="<br/>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    extract($row);
    //echo $plan_id;
    //echo $br;
    //echo $exercise_id;
    //echo $br;
    //echo $exercise_set;
    echo $br;
    $query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exercise WHERE exercise_id='$exercise_id'");
    while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($query2))
    {
        extract ($row2);
        //echo $exercise_name;
    }
}
?>

Exercise Name : <?php echo $exercise_name;?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit-ex.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>
<input type="hidden" name="plan_id" value="<?php echo $plan_id?>"/>
<input type="text" name="member_id" value="<?php echo $member_id;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="exercise_id" value="<?php echo $exercise_id;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="trainer_id" value="<?php echo $trainer_id;?>"/>
<p>Set: <input name="Set" type="text"  /><br/></p>
<p>Weight: <input type="text" name="weight" /><br/></p>
<p>Comment: <input type="text" name="comment" /><br/></p>
<input type="submit" value ="Update The <?php echo $exercise_name;?>"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't post less code then this? You cannot narrow it down any further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
$query.= "member_id = '{$memberadd}', ";
```

You're updating member_id to 2 values in the same query, and the second value `$memberadd` is not set so it is `0`.

Good in this line:

```
$query.= "member_id = {$member_id}, ";
```

Bad in this line:

```
$query.= "member_id = '{$memberadd}', ";
```

**SIDE NOTE: you should stop using mysql_* functions as these are deprecated. Check out [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/PDO)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  single quote (“ ' ”)  to the fields ,

```
   $query = "UPDATE gym_plan SET ";
   $query.= "'exercise_id' = {$exercise_id}, ";
   $query.= "'exercise_set' = '{$Set}', ";
   $query.= "'trainer_id' = {$trainer_id}, ";
   $query.= "'member_id' = {$member_id}, ";
   $query.= "'comment' = '{$comment}', ";
   $query.= "'member_id' = '{$memberadd}', ";
   $query.= "'weight' = '{$weight}' ";
```

Or check out this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html)